# Tables overlap when rendering with WkHtmlToPdf

Tags: pdf, converters, wkhtmltopdf

I have a fairly large HTML file and want to convert it to PDF with WkHtmlToPdf.

After facing several issues one problem is left: There are three tables, from which two are rendered via knockout. When rendering the PDF the tables overlap randomly. Sometimes it's all fine, sometimes all three overlap and most of the times two of them overlap.

We checked the HTML and it looks ok.

Comment: Hey Tim, we had the same problem on a project where we also used wkhtml2pdf. We found out that it was a problem with the timing the tables get delivered. In other words: Maybe your solution would be to first generate the page and everything and then make a pdf out of it

Comment: Hi moesphemie - I thought this is what WkHtmlToPdf does. I tried to create the Pdf via command line. I added the parameters and in the end url of the site which should be rendered and the output file path. Is there anything different from what you do?